# Adding bool column in DataTable with value

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, boolean

i try to add column in datatable :

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BoolProperty", typeof(bool)));
```

and try to set value - false:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["BoolProperty"] = false;
```

But it does not work! Here is code:

```
try
{
    con.server = this.server;
    con.user = this.user;
    con.password = this.password;
    con.OpenConnection();
    con.SqlQuery(Properties.Resources.databaseCatalogResource);
    DataTable dt = con.QueryEx();
    con.da.Fill(dt);
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BoolProperty", typeof(bool)));
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["BoolProperty"] = false;
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Грешка във връзката.", "Грешка");
}
```

This is what happens :
[image: :)]

but i need this column to be unchecked.

Comment: what exception is thrown?

Comment: Remove the try catch (or actually show the error in the catch) so you can see what's going wrong

Comment: Column in datagrid with unchecked chekbox.

Comment: Do you need to add this boolean values for all rows in the table or need to add a new(last) row with this boolean?

Comment: Visit this link http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/show/7432/how-to-add-a-new-column-with-value-to-an-already-existing-datatable-us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a boolean dataColumn with a default value `false` before filling data. (A 
default value is the value that is automatically assigned to the column when a DataRow is created)

```
DataTable dt = con.QueryEx();
var column = new DataColumn("BoolProperty", typeof(bool));
column.DefaultValue = false;
dt.Columns.Add(column);
con.da.Fill(dt);
```

---

lines

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["BoolProperty"] = false;
```

are basically useless. `dr` is a new empty row, isn't added to a table and doesn't change flags in other rows

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BoolProperty", typeof(bool)));
for (int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{
  dt.Rows[i]["BoolProperty"] = "Split";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the DataTable `dt` is already filled with some values from the database using `con.da.Fill(dt);`, and you are adding a new column to this populated table. If you need to add value to this column means you have to do something like this:

```
// Your code
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BoolProperty", typeof(bool)));
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    dr["BoolProperty"] = false;
}
```

Or simply include `false as BoolProperty` in your query that fills the datatable, Which will add a last column in the DataTable in all fetched rows with false

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here loop through the rows to set the default value, but it can also be done inline by using the override of [`Columns.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/632cdz7z(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an [expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)  parameter

For example, to set all rows to boolean true:

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BoolProperty", typeof(bool), "true"));
```

You can also use the expression parameter to set the column value based on other values in the row, which might look something like

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BoolProperty", typeof(bool), "price > 50"));
```

Worth noting though, that adding an expression based column like this also makes the column read-only, as it is intended not to be altered based on (eg) user input.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column Name", typeof(bool), true.ToString())
```

DataColumn has a constructor overload as above. Here it accepts the third parameter as default value for that DataColumn. But the parameter is of string type. So make sure that the default value is typecasted to string.

P.S. I solved this same problem for me using above way.